# Android project with local DB and remote DB

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite

So basically I need an app that would work either the internet is available or not. So naturally I thought: SQLite and MySQL backend. But my question is: what approach should I take?

- Work exclusively on SQLite, and on a button click UPLOAD the work to the server DB?
- Or mix the things like: when Internet is not available work on SQLite, and when Internet is available work on MySQL (while uploading previous work done when internet was offline) ?
- Or some other way maybe?

I do not want to waste time trial/testing both methods. Please tell me those of you who did projects like this how to approach this. I am pretty sure this kind of project is widely encountered.

Also how do I check to see if Internet is available (while not crashing the app), so I'll be able to choose between the 2 work ways (offline and online)?

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to work with SQLite and some script on your backend to generate the updated database to be downloaded from the app, this may be the easieast approach (already done that in one of my app's), but is hard to know what is best for you cz we didn't know how your application works and what is the propuse of your database in your application, if you can explain better your application will be easier to help

Comment: So, the android app's purpose is to collect sales informations from users, and naturally, the information should be centralized on a remote server. But in some cases, some users only use wifi internet, so they will not have internet all the time when they input their reports. They need to fill a report for each customer they visit. Some of them have wifi on site, but some don't. So my user must be able to input his data in the app regardless of the fact that he puts it locally or on the remote server. That is not his concern. The app must have the logic built in to make the sync

Comment: Do you know of any demo of such an app type or tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I would say work on sqlite offline and then when you sense an internet connection sync up. [Checking for network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) is fairly trivial.

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    // sync data
}
```

Comment: So the steps would be: 1. Start app, 2. Check if SQLite DB exists, if not, then create it, 3. if there is Internet then download users table to be able to authenticate the user, if there is no internet... then do what?

Answer (score 0):

I did one such project. My approach was to record everything in the local data base with the main task. I had a background task that took each transaction and attempted to upload it to the back end database, it marked each transaction with a status code as the back end accepted it. I used a sliding window for how often to retry if the upload failed. I would try in a second, then two then four, doubling the wait time until I either succeeded or I reached an hour at which point I tried again every hour no matter what. That worked for us but you could engineer something different if that does not work for you.